# Trying to get pycurl on raspberry pi using python 2.7.3

Tags: python, syntax, raspberry-pi, pycurl

Trying to get pycurl on a raspberry pi using raspian. I enter `sudo apt-get install python-pycurl` in python editor 2.7.3. I receive `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` in red highlighting `apt`. I'm new to this and may be missing something but any help would be much appreciated.